# iOS: UITextField shows as <<error type>>

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, xcode7

I have a UITextField but when I try to print the content of the UITextField I have this error: <>
[image]

Any of you knows what is going on or why this is happening on my project?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Clean derived data, restart Xcode, restart the mac.

Comment: Done but still the same

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this keyword "weak".
Your xib file has a UITextField that doesn't is some subview of a view(strong property).

Comment: maybe use strong instead weak